# keras problems loading custom model from yolov2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, yolo

I've searched around for a couple of answers regarding the `load_model` from `keras` but I still have a question.

I am following this model really closely (https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2), and am training on a custom dataset.

I have done the training which gives me a `yolov2.h5` file, basically model weights to fit into the keras model. But I am encountering some problems with the loading of the model.

After loading the model (in a `separate.py` file)

```py
model = load_model('file_dir/yolov2.h5')
```

First I encounter the issue

```py
NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
```

Which I then searched up to modify my code to add custom objects as such:

```py
model = load_model('file_dir/yolov2.h5', custom_objects={'tf':tf})
```

This clears the first error but results in another

```py
ValueError: Unknown loss function : custom_loss
```

I used the custom_loss function from the yolov2 (https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2/blob/master/frontend.py), so i tried to solve it by

```py
from frontend import YOLO
model = load_model('file_dir/yolov2.h5' custom_objects={'tf':tf, 'custom_loss':YOLO.custom_loss)
```

But ran into another error:

```py
TypeError: custom_loss() missing 1 required positional argument
```

I got rather stuck here because I have no idea how to fit in the parameters for custom_loss. Seek some help regarding this (Don't particularly understand this part since I'm loading my model in a different python script `separate.py`). Thank you so much!

(Edit: This fix doesn't work for me either)

```py
model = load_model('file_dir/yolov2.h5', compile = False)
```

Comment: After training how you are saving `yolov2.h5` model file? using `model.save('yolov2.h5')`?

Comment: The yolov2 model doesn't have an explicit `model.save` (as referred here https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2/blob/master/frontend.py ) but there is a save directory in `model.train`

Comment: the best weights are saved with the `ModelCheckpoint` callback which saves the model after every epoch. https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem, as you already have the network at hand, only save trained weights (like what keras trainer does in callback).
For testing, make model, no need to compile, and then load trained weights using model.load_weights(path/to/saved/weights). 
You also can use "by_name=True" if you make the network in a different way, this time you should keep layer names.

Another option id to manually set weights; for this you will load .h5 file bu "h5py" (h5py.File(path/to/weights, mode='r')) for example (have look how keras do that), then try to correspond layer names of the model and loaded weights.

Comment: What do you mean by make the model? also, the yolov2 (callback in keras) saves a .h5 file, while `model.load_weights` require a hdf5 file?

Comment: During training, you make the model. Do the same in testing, then use keras "load_weights". H5 and hdf5 both work.